# How do I redirect a subdomain to an HTML file?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I've been trying out all sorts of examples to redirect subdomains to files on my server.

So, let's say someone went to apple.domain.com.

Using htaccess, I want it to redirect to domain.com/apple.html

Here's the rules I have right now, which don't work.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1.html [L]
```

Thanks so much in advance for the help.

Comment: That should work as long as `domain.com` and `apple.domain.com` point to the same server and the same document root.

Comment: You can look the Symfony2 .htaccess, it redirects each uri which doesn't correspond with a file in your folder: https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/master/web/.htaccess